# Howto log a Push Notification within Notification Extension (iOS)

Tags: ios, xamarin, push-notification, xamarin.forms, ios-app-extension

I've been trying to log a remote push notification within the `didReceiveNotificationRequest` method of my custom `UNNotificationServiceExtension` class into an existing *SQLite* database.

Unfortunately I'm always receiving a **memory exceeded error**, which causes the notification extension to crash during runtime:

```
Mar 15 10:49:06 MyPhone-iPhone kernel[0] <Notice>: EXC_RESOURCE -> MyApp.iOS.NotificationsExten[9512] exceeded mem limit: ActiveHard 12 MB (fatal)
Mar 15 10:49:06 MyPhone-iPhone kernel[0] <Notice>: 403490.336 memorystatus: killing_specific_process pid 9512 [MyApp.NotificationsExten] (per-process-limit 3) - memorystatus_available_pages: 27259
```

Are there any other ways I could achieve this?
Any help is much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: I would recommend not using SQLite, not using Linq, avoid generics, avoid large images in your data notifications, etc... test with release/linked builds, not debug builds as they are really "fat". But to start you should try Xamarin.iOS 11.10.x as there are new optimizations for memory reductions: https://developer.xamarin.com/releases/ios/xamarin.ios_11/xamarin.ios_11.10/#registrar-optimizations (memory requirement is down 30% for a minimal application and 20% for extensions) (Remember these saving revolve around release/linked builds)

Comment: Thank you @SushiHangover for the great suggestions :) I'll try it again with Xamarin.iOS 11.10.x.